# Is there a disadvantage when using JavaScript instead of an image when caching a web page?

Tags: javascript, image, caching

I'm displaying a bar code on a web page and wondering if there is any disadvantage using JavaScript to do it rather than an image or pdf in terms of caching?

Comment: What do you mean by using javascript to display the bar code?

Comment: @codemonkey - something like this http://zanstra.com/my/Barcode.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript *can* be cached if it's in an external file, so go for it.  Recognise however, that some browsers have Javascript disabled, it's probably more % of users than you would think with the popularity of plugins such as NoScript.

The advantage of an image is it will work on far far more browsers (100%).  It can also be saved, if this is something visitors might do.  Saving the output of a JS file is a little trickier for end users.

So I would favour an image, unless you are generating hundreds of new barcodes and have a solution in JS that makes that job a lot easier.

Cliffnotes: It depends on your situation.  But hopefully I've outlined the most important pros/cons.

Answer (score 2):

Caching will most likely be applied on scripts and images, so in that case there shouldn't be much difference. However, I think your image will change every now and then showing a different bar code? In that case a script that generated the code can have the advantage because the generation code never changes and will stay cached while the differing images must be downloaded again.

Comment: yes I will be showing different bar codes but in that instance the URL will be different. It is a 1 image to 1 URL mapping.

Comment: So the image not gets cached in that case. I you use a script (and the url to the script does not change) this script will most likely be cached.

Answer (score -2):

Any code you 'produce' via javascript cannot be cached

If you are using javascript to load an image or some other document then it will be cached.

Comment: This is not true: you can cache a JavaScript file as well as image files.

Comment: I'm quite aware of that, I said any code that you 'produce' via javascript. You could have a javascript loop which prints out 10,000 words which is not going to be cached because it is output by the javascript